# ‘InitializeCulture’ is not a Member of ASP + Indirect reference is being made to assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors

We've had an issue with the

> BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.remotelogin_aspx'

error for a while, but generally if we just clean and rebuild then it would always work.

I made a branch of the project and now clean/rebuild is not solving the problem. I googled for 2 hours last night trying everything I could find and so far can't figure out how to fix this.

On the error page, in the details below it first pointed to a line of code that I knew had nothing to do with the problem so I commented it out. After that it told me what, presumably, the real issue is. It says

> BC32206: Indirect reference is being made to assembly TUPBase version
>   1.0.5823.3874, which contains 'Viacom.PerformanceManagement.Portal.RemoteLogin'. This Project
>   references a prior version of TUPBase version 1.0.5823.3860. To use
>   'Viacom.PerformanceManagement.Portal.RemoteLogin', you must replace
>   the reference to TUPBase with version 1.0.5823.3874 or higher

The odd thing is that when I look at the dll in the bin directory for the TUPBase project itself, it's only at 3860. I'm not sure how something could be referencing a version that's never even been created yet? I've checked all projects in the solution and they all point to 3860.

I can't find out where in the world it's pulling this 3874 number from since it doesn't seem to exist.

Any ideas how to further investigate this? I'm totally stumped.

FTR, other pages seem to work. And I've followed all the suggestions listed here: http://www.serverintellect.com/support/windowsserver/asp-error-bc30456/

Answer (score 0):

I hope that my answer won't have to be the answer I end up having to choose since it doesn't really deal with whatever the root of the issue is, but I was finally able to fix it by rebuilding just the TUPBase project without rebuilding the entire solution as I had been doing previously. This changed the error to be about MTVBase (which references TUPBase) but the error was otherwise the same. I then recompiled just MTVBase and after that it worked. Then I was also able to clean/rebuild the entire project as usual and it continued to work.

This seems like it could be some kind of bug in Visual Studio.

Just to be clear, TUPBase and MTVBase should be built before the rest of the projects in the solution so it doesn't make sense that I would need to go back and rebuild them afterward. So this still doesn't really address the issue but hopefully this will help someone else.